# Twitter API returning share validations failed

Tags: python, twitter

I'm attempting to post a few retweets but randomly I am getting the error `sharing is not permissible for this status (Share validations failed)`. Their API does not say whether a tweet is retweetable or not and the users must run their own checks. However, I'm not sure if I'm doing these checks correctly. This is a sample status of a tweet that it did not allow me to retweet.

```
{
    "contributors": null, 
    "truncated": false, 
    "text": "[19:51] TTs Espa\u00f1a (1/2): \n1) #EscuchandoMegaStar\n2) #1A\u00f1oSe\u00f1orita\n3) Queralt Castellet\n4) #alarmador\n5) #OrianayTony11Meses", 
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
    "id": 433674861949755392, 
    "favorite_count": 1, 
    "retweeted": false, 
    "coordinates": null, 
    "source": "<a href=\"http://albertovelasco.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">TT Espa\u00f1a</a>", 
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
    "retweet_count": 5, 
    "id_str": "433674861949755392", 
    "favorited": false, 
    "user": {
        "follow_request_sent": false, 
        "profile_use_background_image": true, 
        "default_profile_image": false, 
        "id": 447220528, 
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "verified": false, 
        "profile_text_color": "333333", 
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3785474047/d265fafa5db74297e3db3e517f2c99d5_normal.png", 
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        }, 
        "followers_count": 4152, 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
        "id_str": "447220528", 
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
        "listed_count": 57, 
        "is_translation_enabled": false, 
        "utc_offset": 3600, 
        "statuses_count": 34625, 
        "description": "Soy un robot (beta). Te informo de los Trending Topics en Espa\u00f1a a intervalos variables en funci\u00f3n de la actividad en Twitter. (cuenta sin supervisi\u00f3n humana)", 
        "friends_count": 844, 
        "location": "", 
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3785474047/d265fafa5db74297e3db3e517f2c99d5_normal.png", 
        "following": true, 
        "geo_enabled": false, 
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "screen_name": "ttesbot", 
        "lang": "es", 
        "profile_background_tile": false, 
        "favourites_count": 0, 
        "name": "TT Espa\u00f1a Bot (beta)", 
        "notifications": false, 
        "url": null, 
        "created_at": "Mon Dec 26 16:58:46 +0000 2011", 
        "contributors_enabled": false, 
        "time_zone": "Madrid", 
        "protected": false, 
        "default_profile": true, 
        "is_translator": false
    }, 
    "geo": null, 
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
    "lang": "es", 
    "created_at": "Wed Feb 12 18:51:59 +0000 2014", 
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
    "place": null, 
    "metadata": {
        "iso_language_code": "es", 
        "result_type": "recent"
    }
}
```

If have tried

```
if status['retweeted'] is False:
    print 'Cannot retweet - Already retweeted'
    return False

if status['user']['protected'] is True:
    print 'Cannot retweet - protected user'
    return False

# Code to retweet here
```

Are there any more checks that I should be running? I don't see anymore keys in their JSON response that I need to check. There is a `retweet_count` key but that number shows how many times it has been retweeted by any user, not just me.